# SQL-запрос. Как сделать выборку записей с 2-мя старшими родителями, но без потомков?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Есть таблица `test_table`, в которой 3 поля: *id(int), name(text), parent_id(int).
Пример заполнения таблицы:

```
cfcd2
  ->d3d94
  ->6512b
    ->c74d9
    ->a5771
  ->4e732
    ->6ea9a
  ->d6459
c4ca4
  ->c20ad
    ->c51ce
    ->3c59d
  ->37693
  ->aab32
c81e7
eccbc
  ->67c6a
a87ff
```

Что-то недопонимаю, честно говоря. Мой запрос?

```
select t1.* from `test_table` t1 
left join `test_table` t2 on t2.id=t1.parent 
left join `test_table` t3 on t3.id=t2.parent 
where (t1.parent>0)
```

Забрать записи с 2мя старшими родителями у меня получается, а вот чтобы они при этом еще и без потомков были, вот тут проблема возникла... Пытался к where добавить дополнительное условие с запросом ((select count(t4.*) from `test_table` where (t4.parent=t1.id))=0) , но мускуль не пускает :(

**UPD:**

Решение найдено:

```
select t1.* from `test_table` t1 
join `test_table` t2 on t2.id=t1.parent 
join `test_table` t3 on t3.id=t2.parent 
left join `test_table` t4 on t4.parent=t1.id 
where t4.id is null
```

Comment: Решение найдено: select t1.* from `test_table` t1 join `test_table` t2 on t2.id=t1.parent join `test_table` t3 on t3.id=t2.parent left join `test_table` t4 on t4.parent=t1.id where t4.id is null

Comment: А зачем вам, кстати, t2 и t3 они же представляют одни и те же данные, т.к. связываются по одному и тому же условию

Comment: @Mike , это 2 старших родителя.